# Nightly Builds: Why should I do it?

Tags: nightly-build

Why should I do **Nightly Builds?**

Answer (score 44):

You should do nightly builds to ensure that your codebase stays healthy.

A side effect of doing nightly builds is that it forces the team to create and maintain a fully automated build script.  This helps to ensure that your build process is documented and repeatable.

Automated builds are good at finding the following problems:

- Somebody checked in something that breaks stuff.
- Somebody forgot to check in a necessary file or change.
- Your build scripts no longer work.
- Your build machine is broken.

Doing this nightly ensures that you catch such problems within 24 hours of when they occur.  That is preferable to finding all the problems 24 hours before you are supposed to deliver the software.

You should also, of course, have automated unit tests that are run for each nightly build.

Answer (score 24):

I've personally found continuous integration to be better than nightly builds:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration

I even use it on one man projects, it's amazing how fast you can expose issues and take care of them right there.

Comment: Nightly Builds and Continuous Integration aren't exclusive, you can use the nightly build as use one of the pieces of your continuous build process.

Comment: `I even use it on one man projects` If you work on it yourself, then I suppose you work in the *trunk*? Or when you decide to work in a *branch*, then why integratie continuously with the *trunk*? So what is different in a *one man project* from just programming and syncing your code with the *Trunk*, and make sure it can build and passes the (automated) tests before syncing the code, or doing the continuous integration practise? And some work may span more days before it can be integrated in the *trunk* => then continuous integration is impractical. Or learn me what the difference is please.

Answer (score 20):

I've been doing build engineering (among other things) for 16 years.  I am a strong believer in build-early, build-often, continuous integration.  So the first thing I do with a project is establish how it will be built (Java: [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/); .NET: [NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/) or [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wea2sca5(VS.80).aspx)) and how it will be managed ([Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) or some other version control).  Then I'll add Continuous Integration ([CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) or [CruiseControl.NET](http://ccnet.thoughtworks.com/)) depending upon the platform, then let the other developers loose.

As the project grows, and the need for reports and documentation grows, eventually the builds will take longer to run.  At that point I'll split the builds into continuous builds (run on checkin) that only compile and run unit tests and daily builds that build everything, run all the reports, and build any generated documentation.  I may also add a delivery build that tags the repository and does any additional packaging for a customer delivery.  I'll use fine-grained build targets to manage the details, so that any developer can build any part of the system -- the Continuous Integration server use the exact same build steps as any developer.  Most importantly, we never deliver a build for testing or a customer that wasn't built using the build server.

That's what I do -- here's why I do it (and why you should too):

Suppose you have a typical application, with multiple projects and several developers.  While the developers may start with a common, consistent development environment (same OS, same patches, same tools, same compilers), over the course of time their environments will diverge.  Some developers will religiously apply all security patches and upgrades, others won't.  Some developers will add new (maybe better) tools, others won't.  Some will remember to update their complete workspace before building; others will only update the part of the project they're developing.  Some developers will add source code and data files to the project, but forget to add them to source control.  Others will write unit tests that depend upon specific quirks of their environment.  As a consequence, you'll quickly see the ever-popular "Well, it builds/works on my machine" excuses.

By having a separate, stable, consistent, known-good server for building your application, you'll easily discover these sorts of problems, and by running builds from every commit, you'll be able to pinpoint when a problem crept into the system.  Even more importantly, because you use a separate server for building and packaging your application, it will always package everything the same way, every time.  There is nothing worse than having a developer ship a custom build to a customer, have it work, and then have no idea how to reproduce the customizations.

Answer (score 12):

When I saw this question, first I searched for [**Joel Spolsky's**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky) answer.  Bit disappointed, so I planned to add it here.

Hope everyone is aware of [**Joel Test on Careers**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109280/should-the-joel-test-on-careers-be-updated).

From his blog on [**The Joel Test: 12 Steps to Better Code**](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html)

> **3. Do you make daily builds?**
>
> When you're using source control, sometimes one programmer
>   accidentally checks in something that breaks the build. *For example,
>   they've added a new source file, and everything compiles fine on their
>   machine, but they forgot to add the source file to the code
>   repository. So they lock their machine and go home, oblivious and
>   happy. But nobody else can work, so they have to go home too, unhappy.*
>
> Breaking the build is so bad (and so common) that it helps to make
>   daily builds, to insure that no breakage goes unnoticed. *On large
>   teams, one good way to insure that breakages are fixed right away is
>   to do the daily build every afternoon at, say, lunchtime. Everyone
>   does as many checkins as possible before lunch. When they come back,
>   the build is done. If it worked, great! Everybody checks out the
>   latest version of the source and goes on working. If the build failed,
>   you fix it, but everybody can keep on working with the pre-build,
>   unbroken version of the source.*
>
> On the Excel team we had a rule that whoever broke the build, as their
>   "punishment", was responsible for babysitting the builds until someone
>   else broke it. This was a good incentive not to break the build, and a
>   good way to rotate everyone through the build process so that everyone
>   learned how it worked.

Though I haven't got an opportunity to make daily builds, I'm a great fan of it.

Still not convinced?  Check out the brief here in [**Daily Builds Are Your Friend!!**](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000023.html)

Answer (score 8):

You don't actually, what you should be wanting is Continuous Integration and automatic testing (which is a step further than nightly builds).

If you are in any doubt you should read [this article by Martin Fowler about Continuous Integration](http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html).

To summarize, you want to build and test as early and often as possible to spot errors immediately so they can be fixed while what you were trying to achieve when you caused them is still fresh in your mind.

Comment: Nightly Builds and Continuous Integration aren't exclusive, you can use the nightly build as use one of the pieces of your continuous build process.

Comment: Quite late response, but... according to Martin Fowler, CI and Nightly Builds *are* mutually exclusive. If you depend on nightly builds then it follows you are not doing *true* CI, period. Of course, if that's a bad thing or not, it's another discussion entirely.

Answer (score 8):

I'd actually recommend to do builds every time you check in. In other words, I'd recommend setting up a Continuous Integration system.

The advantages of such a system and other details can be found [in Fowler's article](http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html) and [on the Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_Integration) among other places.

In my personal experience, it's a matter of Quality Control: every time code (or tests, which can be seen as a form of requirements) are modified, bugs might be creeping in. To ensure quality you should make a fresh build of the product as it would be shipped and perform all the tests available. The more often this is done, the less likely bugs will be allowed to form a colony. Therefore, daily (nightly) or continuous cycles are preferred.

In addition, whether you restrict access o your project to developers or a larger group of users, a nightly build enables everyone to be on the 'latest version', minimizing the pain of merging their own contributions back into the code.

Comment: a build on every checkin is not always a realistic, or even desireable, goal.

Answer (score 4):

You want to do builds on a *regular schedule* in order to catch problems with integration of code between developers. The reason you want to do this *nightly*, as opposed to weekly or on some longer schedule, is that the longer you wait to discover these kinds of problems, the more difficult it will be to resolve them. The practice of doing a build on every check in (Continuous Integration) is just taking the nightly build process to a logical extreme.

The side benefit of having a repeatable build process is important in the long run as well. If you work on a team where there are multiple projects going on, then at some point you will need to be able to easily recreate an old build, perhaps for creating a patch. :(

The more you can automate the build process, the more time you will save for each subsequent build. It also takes the build process itself off of the critical path of delivering the final product, which should make your manager happy. :)

Answer (score 3):

It also depends on the size and structure of the team(s) working on your project. If there are different teams relying on each others API, it may make a lot of sense to have nightly builds for frequent integration. If you're hacking away with only one or two team mates it may or may not be worth it.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the complexity of your product continuous integration may or may not be able run a full test suite.

Imagine Cisco testing a router with the literally 1000s of different setups to test. To run a full test suite on some products takes time. Sometimes weeks. So you need builds for different purposes. A nightly build can be the basis for a more thorough test suite.

Answer (score 2):

Well ... I guess it depends a lot on your project, of course. If it's just your hobby project, with no releases, no dependencies, and noone but you submitting code, it might be overkill.

If, on the other hand, there's a team of developers all submitting code, automatic nightly builds will help you ensure the quality of the code in the repository. If someone does something that "breaks the build" for all others, it will quickly be noticed. It is possible to break the build without noticing, for instance by forgetting to add a new file to the repository, and nightly builds in a centralized location will detect these quite quickly.

There are of course other possible benefits, I'm sure others will supply them. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think they are very important especially on projects with more than 1 person. The team needs to know ASAP if someone:

- checks in a bad file
- doesn't check in a file
- ...

Answer (score 2):

Any build automation is better than no build automation :-)

Personally, I prefer daily builds - that way if the build doesn't work then everyone is around to get it fixed.

In fact, if at all possible then Continuous Integration builds are the way to go (i.e. a build on every check-in) as that minimizes the amount of change between a build and so makes it easy to tell who broke the build and also easy to fix the build.

Answer (score 1):

Nightly builds are only necessary for significantly large projects (when it takes too long to build it often throughout the day). If you have a small project that does not take long to build you can build it as you get functional pieces of code done so that you know that you did not mess anything up in the procees. However, with larger projects this is not possible so it is important to build the project just so that you know that everything is still in working order

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons, some will be more applicable than others

- If your project is being worked on by two or more people
- It's a good way to grab the latest version of code that you aren't working on
- A nightly build provides a slice in time of the current state of the code
- A nightly build will give you a stable build if you need to send code to people

Answer (score 0):

Nightly builds aren't always necessary - I think they're only really useful on big projects. But if you're on a big project, a nightly build is a good way of checking that everything is working - you can run all your tests (unit tests, integration tests), build all your code - in short, verify that nothing is broken in your project.

If you've got a smaller project your build and test times will be shorter so you can probably afford to do more regular builds.

Answer (score 0):

Nightly builds are ideal for performing static code analysis (see qalab and the projects it collects stats from if you are in java world). Unfortunately, this is something that's rarely done.