# What artifacts to save for a released build?

Tags: deployment, build-process

So, I now know [what to save from nightly builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230595/what-artifacts-to-save-for-a-nightly-build).  What about when I give something to customers?

For example, I probably want to save debugging information (e.g. PDB).

What else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use:

- installers
- binaries
- pdbs
- tag of source files
- any other source files that might not be in svn - for example config.status
- build log

You made me wonder if I'm missing anything important

Comment: Why are any source files used in the build not under your VCS - SVN in your case?  Every such file is a fertile source of problems later.

Answer (score 1):

- Compiler and library version information (it may not be part of the build log).  Somebody else mentioned the whole binaries.
- Linker map file (it can sometimes help the remote debugging of a problem).
- Unstripped executable (if on a Unix system you strip it the executable before making it available to clients).

Answer (score 1):

For the SDK releases we do include:

- PDB and XML for the libraries (packaged with the latest snapshot of the samples)
- Packaged snapshot of sources from SVN (just because we can)
- Link to the online documentation (docs are generated from the source automatically)

Answer (score 0):

Trace messages don't necessarily need to be generated by default but the possibility to enable them can be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Results and Information generated from ATPs that are run on the build (probably as part of the build process).